# How to delete items from ListField

Tags: blackberry

I want to delete items and refresh it. I have been trying for 2 days, no luck.

`listField.delete(index)` doesn't work.

If you can provide me appropriate solution, I will give you all of my reputation.

Comment: Do you get exception or nothing changes?

Comment: No, I don't get any exception. Just nothing changes.

Comment: `listField.delete(index)` should not be a problem. I think there might be a problem with your own implementation. You can be more specific by giving us your code and we could try solving this.

Comment: You are right, but I can't share codes. It is a little bit complicated. So should I call some other methods, like repaint, after calling `delete()`.

Comment: try doing it some dummy data and step by step complicate it by adding your actual codes. You should see where the bug is by using this way.

Comment: just reomve the elements from the vector you using to manipulate the list,

Comment: I tried everything, but it works only when I push another page and come back to the page which has listfield. I think it is about ListCallback. I want to do delete action when I am waiting in the page. I wrote a thread for this, but page is not refreshing...

Answer (score 1):

You'll probably have to override it to remove the item from your data backing the list, and then call `listField.setSize(newSize)`. Since it doesn't know what sort of data structure you are using to push elements into it, it can't be sure how to remove them.

For example, if you have a Vector that stores your data, override `delete()` to remove the element, and then call `setSize(vector.size())`. If your ListFieldCallback is stored somewhere else, just make a wrapper call to a similar `delete()` method in your callback.